# Maven - peer not authenticated

Tags: maven, ubuntu

A few days ago my maven stopped working. To be more specific it stops download dependencies. Below I note bunch of information and steps which I did in order to find solution.

1. I double checked settings.xml - this file is used also by my colleagues and they haven't any problems
2. I installed Maven 3.0.4, 3.0.5, 3.1.0 - it always fail during download dependencies
3. I have 3 computers - 2 with Ubuntu and 1 with Windows. On Windows it works great, on both Ubuntu it doesn't.
4. `mvn clean install` generates in debug mode something like that: `Could not transfer artifact junit:junit:pom:3.8.1 from/to central...: peer not authenticated` [stacktrace](http://pastebin.com/QRHYAQS0)
5. I tried to use additional parameters `mvn -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true clean install`
    but it fails also. Output in debug mode ends with: `Server key: Could not create EC public key: CKR_DOMAIN_PARAMS_INVALID`
6. If I add all dependencies manually (copy&paste from my colleagues ~/.m2 directory) then `mvn clean install` works correctly. So, it seems to be a problem only with downloading.

Does anyone have any suggestions what can be wrong?

Comment: Please show the full error output in particular the stacktracefrom number 4

Comment: I attached a stacktrace to point 4 (http://pastebin.com/QRHYAQS0)

Comment: This looks `(https://companyname.de/artifactory/plugins-release): peer not authenticated` your local repository authentication data is not correct or not configured in settings.xml file.

Comment: Unfortunatelly settings.xml file is correct. All credencials work for others. I found a solution. If you are interested look at correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem. Be sure you have rights to write into `{jdk_directory}/security/java.security` file (in my case `/etc/java-7-openjdk/security/java.security)` and if so, then modify it this way:

from:

```
#security.provider.9=sun.security.ec.SunEC
security.provider.9=sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11 ${java.home}/lib/security/nss.cfg
```

to

```
security.provider.9=sun.security.ec.SunEC
#security.provider.9=sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11 ${java.home}/lib/security/nss.cfg
```

It fixed problem on all my computers (all with maven 3.0.4)